# Top Questions of the Week #20

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 20 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Comment: Sorry it's late this week, folks. Just started an internship, so I've been rather busy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a user came into the chat asking about hardware recommendations, it clear the issue wasn't just a matter of knowing what hardware to get, but rather a lack of basic understanding on how to judge and compare unfamiliar hardware. Starting a good general-purpose computer-buying guide seemed like a great way to help out those that simply have no clue where to begin and would actually give us a way to teach those asking for shopping recommendations how to figure out an answer localized for their needs instead of simply closing their answer with no real leads on how to solve their issue.

> ### [When looking forward to build a computer, how do I know what to buy?](https://superuser.com/questions/297274/how-do-i-know-what-hardware-to-buy-to-meet-my-needs)
>
> While Stack Exchange [does not permit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) shopping recommendations, it doesn't provide any general advice to consider when buying hardware. So, instead of just telling those that ask what to buy that it's not allowed, let's tell them how to figure out what they need.

Comment: I was going to post this.  +1 +1 +1.